# UITextView delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextview

Swift beginner here. I am having quite a tough time getting my `UITextView` delegate methods to call. I have looked through many other questions, to no avail.

I have a `UITextView` set up in a `ViewConroller`. It looks like this:

[image: UITextView in ViewController]

There is a `UIImageView` directly above the `UITextView`, and everything is wrapped in a navigation controller, should be no big deal.

I made sure to connect the View from the storyboard to my `ViewController`:

[image: Storyboard Connection]

From the storyboard I CTRL+Drag the `UITextView` right below the class declaration. This produces the line:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Description: UITextView!
```

Class declaration:

```
class ImageTextViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

(I need the other delegates for my `NavigationController` and `UIImageView`)

I then declare the delegate as so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.Description.delegate = self
```

Now the following delegate method should be called when I finish editing the `UITextView`. But for some reason it is not firing!

```
private func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool{
    print("we are done editing")
    spotDescription.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

How do I get that to fire properly for my `UITextView`?

Comment: Your storyboard connection is `TextImageViewController` & you are writing into `ImageTextViewController `

Answer (score 3):

textViewDidEndEditing method do not have return value. You have to write this

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("we are done editing")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jack is right.
In the image titled `Storyboard Connection` your viewController seems to be titled `TextImageViewController`, while in the class declaration example is titled `ImageTextViewController`.

The ViewController in the Storyboard and the ViewController should both be the same.

Андрей is also right.
TextViewDidEndEditing method does not have a return value.

lindanordstrom also makes a good point:
TextViewDidEndEditing shouldn't be private.

Comment: Yep, and TextViewDidEndEditing shouldn't be private either.